# The CPU visible in Resource Manager are physical cores or logical processors?

Tags: performance, operating-systems, cpu-usage, cpu-cores

The Resource Manager that pops out from Task Manager in Windows Operating Systems shows CPU consumption on the CPU tab for each of the different CPUs.

I get 4 CPUs on my tab. Are they all physical processors or logical processors?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my Intel i7-920 display 8 cores instead of 4 cores?](http://superuser.com/questions/96001/why-does-my-intel-i7-920-display-8-cores-instead-of-4-cores), [I have an intel I3 processor by my task manager CPU history shows 4 graphs does that mean I have four cores?](http://superuser.com/questions/607226/i-have-an-intel-i3-processor-by-my-task-manager-cpu-history-shows-4-graphs-does)

Comment: They are always logical CPU's in Windows eyes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you're using a desktop or a laptop that has a single processor. Also likely is that it is an AMD64 or Intel64 processor with multiple cores.

Task Manager generally shows performance across the cores in the system. If you had multiple processors, it generally puts a block around the cores within a particular processor so the user can see the performance both across the cores as well as across processors.

Without knowing more, I'm around 97% confident you're seeing the 4 cores of a quad-core processor.

Answer (score 1):

The CPU's visible in Task Manager are *Logical cores*, I have a server with 4 Physical processors which equate to 24~ logical cores, each of which is visible on my task manager.